# From where i can find cognito pool url to be used in the mentioned code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

Use case 19. Using this library with Cognito's federated sign in on mobile devices. Use flutter_webview (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to navigate to Cognito's authorize URL. Use flutter_webview's navigationDelegate to catch the redirect to myapp://?code=<AUTH_CODE>. Make a POST request to Cognito's token URL to get your tokens. Create the session and user with the tokens.

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _webViewController = Completer<WebViewController>();
  Widget getWebView() {
    var url = "https://${COGNITO_POOL_URL}" +
      ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Google&redirect_uri=" +
      "myapp://&response_type=CODE&client_id=${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}" +
      "&scope=email%20openid%20profile%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin";
    return
      WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) ' +
            'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController.complete(webViewController);
        },
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith("myapp://?code=")) {
            String code = request.url.substring("myapp://?code=".length);
            signUserInWithAuthCode(code);
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      );
  }

  final userPool = CognitoUserPool(
    'ap-southeast-1_xxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  );
  static Future signUserInWithAuthCode(String authCode) async {
    String url = "https://${COGNITO_POOL_URL}" +
        ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" +
        "${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&code=" + authCode + "&redirect_uri=myapp://";
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception("Received bad status code from Cognito for auth code:" +
          response.statusCode.toString() + "; body: " + response.body);
    }

    final tokenData = json.decode(response.body);

    final idToken = CognitoIdToken(tokenData['id_token']);
    final accessToken = CognitoAccessToken(tokenData['access_token']);
    final refreshToken = CognitoRefreshToken(tokenData['refresh_token']);
    final session = CognitoUserSession(idToken, accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken);
    final user = CognitoUser(null, userPool, signInUserSession: session);

    // NOTE: in order to get the email from the list of user attributes, make sure you select email in the list of
    // attributes in Cognito and map it to the email field in the identity provider.
    final attributes = await user.getUserAttributes();
    for (CognitoUserAttribute attribute in attributes) {
      if (attribute.getName() == "email") {
        user.username = attribute.getValue();
        break;
      }
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

I have tried to find in Cognito properties, but there nothing called pool url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want there is the Cognito domain, which is under "App Integration" tab, subsection "Domain". Your code is already adding the .amazoncognito.com so you will just need the first part of the domain. If you do not have a domain listed under Domain, you can use Actions->Create Cognito Domain to create one.

[image]